# Laravel vs. Ajax: incorrect routing

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I'm trying to populate "position" dropdown based on "department". The Ajax call is triggered on `change` event of the "department" dropdown.

The problem is that the Ajax call can't reach the correct route:

- with `url: 'ajax/get-position'` - the url is: localhost/public/join/ajax/get-position?dept_id=5
- with `url: '/ajax/get-position'` - the url is: localhost/ajax/get-position?dept_id=5

Both of the URLs are wrong and I have no idea why. Especially this **/join/** in the first point is a mystery to me. The correct URL should be **localhost/public/ajax/get-position?dept_id=5**. I believe there's some kind of a conflict in the routing, however I'm not sure where.

The Ajax call is made on **localhost/public/join/editor** page.

**JS:**

```
...
...
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/get-position',
    data: {
        dept_id: value
    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        //
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        //
    }
});
...
...
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('join/editor',
    array(
        'uses' => 'DefaultController@showEditorRegistration',
        'as' => 'editorRegistration'
    )
);

Route::post('join/editor',
    array(
        'uses' => 'DefaultController@createEditor',
        'as' => 'createEditor'
    )
);

// ROUTE FOR AJAX CALL
Route::get('ajax/get-position',
    array(
        'uses' => 'DefaultController@getPositionsByDepartment',
    )
);
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The JavaScript is in an external file. If I put the JS directly in blade.php view and use `URL::route('routename')` as Ajax `url` value - all works fine. However, simply using `url: ajax/get-position` - does not. Crazy world.

Comment: What error message do you get if you try to hit the `get-position` route directly in the browser?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz There's none. The route is fine when accessed directly in the browser. Only Ajax call makes problems. The incorrect URLs I mentioned in the post throw 404.

Comment: I setup a quick project to test an ajax call and didn't run into an issue. To troubleshoot, try replacing the second parameter in your `ajax/get-position` route to a closure and return test data. E.g.: `Route::get('ajax/get-position', function(){return 'worked';});`. If you add that and fire it via ajax do you get "worked" returned?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz Unfortunately it's not returned. It cannot be returned because Ajax still doesn't get to the right route. I put the JS script into a blade.php file and used `URL::route('getPositionsByDepartment')` as Ajax `url` value - and it works. But I want to keep the JS in an external file and simply use 'ajax/get-position', which SHOULD work based on routing - and it doesn't :/

Comment: That's weird. So when you add `URL::route('getPositionsByDepartment')` into the view and inspect the resulting ajax in your browser's dev tools, what's the full url that it inserts?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz For department of ID=5 it's: localhost/public/ajax/get-position?dept_id=5 - and it's totally correct. As is the response. My JS file is under public/static/js/ajax.js. I'm pretty sure it's one of the other routes that messes something up - hence the "/join/" in the "almost correct URL" from the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67818/discussion-between-chris-schmitz-and-lesssugar).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure, but based on our conversation about the details of your project I think the issue has to do with the location of your document root. the `public` directory should never show up in any of your laravel project's urls.

I created a demo project to demonstrate a simple interaction with [Laravel and Ajax](https://github.com/chris-schmitz/Demo_LaravelAndAjax). It's a vanilla laravel project with slight alterations to the `hello` view.

Checkout the project, navigate into the public folder, and use the following command to spin up an ad-hoc phpserver:

```
php -S localhost:8002
```

You can then go to the url `http://localhost:8002` to get to the homepage.

If you inspect the link on the home page and look at the url that is generated with the `URL` facade for the route `tester`. The URL doesn't include the `public` directory:

```
http://localhost:8003/tester
```

You can also look at the ajax setup and see that you can use the `tester` route as well.

```
    $('#getbutton').click( function (){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'tester'

                }).complete(function (a){
                    alert(a.responseText);
                }).error(function (a){
                   console.log(a);
                });
    });
```

Using either the link or the ajax call on button click will hit the `tester` route in the routes file:

```
Route::get('tester',[ 'as' => 'tester', 'uses' => function (){
    return 'worked';
}]);
```

The link can hit the route via the route name `tester` assigned in the routes file, and the ajax request can hit the route from the query string.

The routes in your project look ok and using `ajax/get-position` as your url in the ajax call shouldn't be an issue.

Give this project a try. Even if the issue isn't a webroot one, hopefully it will help you figure out where your issue is coming from.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, that's useful. I'm not sure either but it seems like the root location is the only thing that could be incorrect. Soon I will be testing this on production, we'll see. Until then I'm saving the route URL in a hidden form input, and retrieving it from there into my JS. Again, thanks.